# Setting multiple borders on UIView

Tags: ios, ios6, uiview, uikit, quartz-graphics

As I cannot find any questions/answers for this, I imagine it is not possible.

Is there anyway to set multiple borders on a `UIView`.

I am currently setting a standard border with `.layer.borderWidth` and `layer.borderColor`. I am wondering if I can add a multiple strokes/borders effect to the view.

I need a border of 4.0f in white then another 1.0f in another color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three solutions I can think of:

- nest a UIView in another one, define one border for each;
- draw the border yourself in `-(void)drawRect`;
- use an `UIImageView` with a resizable; stretchable image of your borders as background (the best solution performance-wise).

Answer (score 2):

That isn't possible with a single `UIView` instance without adding layers.

What you can do is create a view that is larger than necessary, set its border appropriately, then add a `CALayer` and position it where you want the inner border and set its border properties appropriately.

Using `CALayers` is typically faster than full blown `UIView`, but you can also just have a nested `UIView` to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert two layers of different widths using this extension:

```
extension CALayer {
    func addGradientBorder(colors:[UIColor],width:CGFloat = 1) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.bounds.size)
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1.0,y:1.0)
        gradientLayer.colors = colors.map({$0.cgColor})

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = width
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        gradientLayer.mask = shapeLayer

        self.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

Use this with different widths/colors to get the desired effect:

```
yourView.layer.addGradientBorder(colors:[UIColor.black,UIColor.black] , width: 20)
yourView.layer.addGradientBorder(colors:[UIColor.white,UIColor.white] , width: 10)
```

Output looks like the following image with outer white border and inner black border:

[image: Output looks like this with outer white border and inner black border]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, you will have to fake borders by adding `UIView`'s with a background color to your xib/view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

I'm adding shadow with alpha 1 which will act as the inner border. And the normal border is given as outer border.

```
yourView.frame = CGRectInset(yourView.frame, -borderWidth, -borderWidth);
yourView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
yourView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;


yourView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
yourView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```